# passing parameters to zend paginationControl partial

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, partial

I have a page that displays a lot of data, including Zend_Paginator.
The page action is `/po/fetch?id=someID`.

what i want to do is to pass the "id" parameter to zend paginationControl so the pagination links will be something like `/po/fetch?id=someID&page=somePage`. unfortunally i can't find anywhere explanation on how i can pass that parameter to the paginationControl.

my call to paginationControl:

```
echo $view->paginationControl($paginator, 'Sliding',$control, $params);
```

where `$params = array('id' => someID`

and my pagination partial is:

```
<a href=<?= $url.'&page='.$this->first; ?> id="first"> First </a>

<a href=<?= $url.'&page='.$this->previous; ?> id="previous">&lt; Previous</a>

<?php 
foreach($this->pagesInRange as $page) {
?>
        <a href="<?= $url.'&page='.$page; ?>">.$page.</a>  | ;
<?php 
}
?>

<a href=<?= $url.'&page='.$this->next;?> id="next"> Next &gt;</a>

<a href=<?= $url.'&page='.$this->last; ?> id="last"> Last </a>
```

and I want `$url` to be of the specified form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$this->id
```

Answer (score 9):

Hey Try this, It will surely work.....

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $page,'id'=>'1')); ?>">
    <?php echo $page; ?>
</a>
```

Here `1` is given as the id you have to pass the id you want.......
Like

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $page,'id'=>$param['id'])); ?>">
        <?php echo $page; ?>
    </a>
```

Comment: for some reason $param is empty in my case...@vredniy's answer worked for me.

Comment: the above $param[] method would only work where an array of that value and key were set.  the `$this->id` worked for you because you have singleton $this object set

Answer (score 3):

Your example code doesn't show how `$url` is populated, but you really should be using the URL [ViewHelper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html).

So, for example - your previous link would become:

```
<a href=<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->previous)); ?> id="previous">&lt; Previous</a>
```

This will return a proper URL to the current page with the `page` parameter set to `$this->previous`. So if the current url is `/users/view?foo=bar&page=5`, the above code would output `/users/view?foo=bar&page=4` for the previous link. Notice how any query parameters that are already present are preserved.

So, if the `id` parameter is already present on the URL showing your paginator, the above code will "just work". However, if you still need to add the `id` parameter, you can do so like this:

```
<a href=<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->previous, 'id' => $this->id)); ?> id="previous">&lt; Previous</a>
```

To continue from our previous example, this code would output the following url: `/users/view?foo=bar&page=4&id={someId}`

Here is the reference documentation for the URL ViewHelper:

> **url($urlOptions, $name, $reset):**
>   Creates a URL string based on a named
>   route. $urlOptions should be an
>   associative array of key/value pairs
>   used by the particular route.

One last note - the `$reset` (third) parameter of the URL ViewHelper will come in very handy. The default behavior is to preserve any query parameters of the current request but calling `$this->url(array(), 'default', true)` with `true` for the `$reset` parameter will basically remove all parameters except for the ones you specify in `$urlOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same issue so I have used code given below in partial paginator.

I have created a function in paginator partial view file(`control.phtml`) or may be different.

```
function queryStr($p){
    $params = $array = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getQuery();
    $params['page']=$p;
    $str='?';
    foreach($params as $k=>$v){
        if($v)
           $str .= $k.'='.$v.'&';
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Now for links I am using code given below.

```
<a href="<?php echo queryStr($page); ?>">
```

Instead of

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $page)); ?>">
```

I am sure it will be helpful to others as well.